# Fatal error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I am using QT 4.8.
I want to connect it with MySql database.
Initially I was getting this error MySQL driver not found. I googled it and found that I need to manually create drivers for it.
I run mysql.pro project through QT creator to create libmysql.dll, but I get this error

LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

Here is the code I am using.

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/PROGRA~2/MySQL/MYSQLS~1.5/include
LIBS += C:/PROGRA~2/MySQL/MYSQLS~1.5/lib/libmysql.lib

SOURCES = main.cpp

include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

I checked my include directory, the lib file is present there.
I am stuck on this problem since 3 days.
It would be great if someone can help me out here.

Thanks :)

Comment: This 'libmysql.lib' can't be found in the path. Thats why you are getting linker error. Make sure that this should be linked to your project.

Comment: The file is present in the file specified. But it still can't open it

Answer (score 0):

I provide you here a sample project file. Please change it according to your path settings:

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

LIBS += C:\mysql-5.6.13-win32\mysql-5.6.13-win32\lib\libmysql.lib
INCLUDEPATH += C:\mysql-5.6.13-win32\mysql-5.6.13-win32\include
SOURCES = main.cpp OTHER_FILES += mysql.json
include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

Comment: I made changes to my code according to your answers.
I get this error now.
`macro name debug\+ is invalid in C:\Qt\4.8.0\src\plugins\sqldrivers\build\win32\Debug\Makefile.Debug line 159`

Comment: Have you used qmake and make (from your compiler toolchain) from the console or did you tried it from the QtCreator? Please clean up the code you produced from the first try (make clean -> toolchain dependent) and subsequently call qmake. Then try to compile. And do not use QtCreator for this (just use the console -> don't forget to make sure your PATH is right) to prevent QtCreator screw the standard build path.

Comment: Hi I tried it.
I get this error now 
`NMAKE : fatal error V1077: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe return code '0x460'
NMAKE : fatal error V1077: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe return code '0x2'`
Please tell me how to fix it

Comment: Have you used nmake from the Visual Studio shell? You have to start this from the VS shell to set the environment variables right. The linker error could also be indicating that it cannot find the mysql lib (maybe you used the wrong path).

Comment: From the console I dont get the linker error.
I am getting this fatal error while calling nmake. I still get it when I am calling it from visual studio command prompt now.

Comment: Well, the linker probably does not find a library (in this case i guess it is the mysql lib). Just to quickly check this, try to copy the libs of mysql to the folder of the pro file. I assume it created the object files, so at least the compiler could find the include path. Now we must check what libs the linker is missing and why these libs are not found.